# jQuery keydown keyup function fires every other time

Tags: jquery

I have this small snippet to change a bit of html when a user presses the Alt key, and then change it back when they release it.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {

    if(e.altKey) {

        $('#title').html('foo');

        $(this).keyup(function(e) {

            $('#title').html('bar');

        });

    }

});
```

This works fine the first time, but the 2nd time it doesn't. The 3rd does work, 4th doesn't etc...

Why do the key events only seem to get triggered every other key press?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using this in Firefox?  If so, Firefox will steal focus when you press <kbd>alt</kbd>, preventing the document from getting the keypress, and give it back on the next <kbd>alt</kbd> press.  Also, you are assigning a keyup handler to the document ***every*** time you press <kbd>alt</kbd>, so by the 10th time, you are calling keyup 9 times.  You need to separate the two:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.altKey) {
        $('#title').html('foo');
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    $('#title').html('bar');

    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HZ5gw/

**Note:** in jQuery, `return false` is the same as doing `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation`, and stopping callbacks.  It looks like Chrome needs `preventDefault()` and firefox needs `stopPropagation`, so `return false` accomplishes both of these.  You could also just call each of those instead.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I was using chrome. I did originally have the code the same as you've posted as above but without the return false part. I just tried re-writing it to attempt to get around the problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an issue with Chrome.

Adding `e.preventDefault();` seems to do the trick.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xPMFj/1/)

Comment: Looks like Chrome does something different than Firefox.  Firefox needs `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent it from stealing focus in this case.